# Passing params to match type in React component

Tags: typescript

I have types like this:

```
export type DataType = {
  id: string;
  type: string;
  configuration: { input: string };
};

export type InputType =
  | { configJsonUrl: string }
  | { configJsObject: DataType }
  | { rawData: { [key: string]: string } };


export type ComponentInputType = {
  input: InputType;
  formSubmitAction: () => void;
};
```

Then I have a React component that uses the `ComponentInputType`:

```
const Component = ({
  input,
  formSubmitAction,
}: ComponentInputType ): JSX.Element => {

// code to generate the component

}
```

To use the component, I have my data and the function like so:

```
const func = () => 'dummy';

const adhocData = {
  session: 'session',
  foo: 'foo',
  bar: 'bar',
};
```

But I am getting an error when passing the params like so:

```
<Component input={adhocData} formSubmitAction={func} />
```

I get the error on `input={adhocData}`. The error is `Type '{ session: string; foo: string; bar: string; }' is not assignable to type 'InputType'`

How to pass the data properly?

I tried `rawData={adhocData}` instead of `input={adhocData}` as well but that is not working either.

Comment: What's unclear from the message? `{ session: string; foo: string; bar: string; }` is indeed not assignable to any member of `InputType`. Are you trying to use the third member of the union, i.e. `input={{ rawData: adhocData }}`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Typically we use `=` to pass the value but in this case I have to pass `input={{ rawData: adhocData }}` which is new to me & hence not completely clear.

Comment: ...that _is_ using `=` to pass the value. This is basic JS - the value is an object. Any expression, including an object literal, can be interpolated in JSX, not just names.

Answer (score 1):

Extend your `adhocData` to have a `rawData` field in the root, something like this:

```
const adhocData = {
  rawData: {
    session: 'session',
    foo: 'foo',
    bar: 'bar',
  }
};
```

Passing this object to the component should solve your issue:

```
<Component input={adhocData} formSubmitAction={func} />
```

As a sidenote, I also noticed that your `func` function returns a string, so you may get another typescipt error regarding to that.
You can change the function signature to `const func = () => void;` to prevent getting the error.

Comment: Thanks. This is a pretty good solution. However I need both the key `rawData` and the object `adhocData` in my component so, I will use `input={{ rawData: adhocData }}`

Comment: @moys _"I need both the key `rawData` and the object `adhocData` in my component"_ - what? This answer is exactly equivalent to what I put in my comment above. This isn't even a React question at this point, just basic JS objects - the value of `input` is an object with a single object property named `rawData`, which is _what your type requires_.

Comment: You have right @jonrsharpe, I didn't see your comment when I started answering, it's an equivalent of yours.